# Is there a QTimer::singleShot equivalent in C# Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, qt, timer, threadpool

Is there an analog to the following static function from the Qt library in Windows Forms?

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#singleShot

The best I can come up with is the following:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) =>
{
    Thread.Sleep(someNumberOfMilliseconds);
    DoDelayedWorkHere();
});
```

**UPDATE**

This does the trick using System.Windows.Forms.Timer.

```
var timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
timer.Interval = someNumberOfMilliseconds;
timer.Tick += (o, args) =>
    {
        timer.Stop();
        DoDelayedWorkHere();
    };
timer.Start();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

QTimer is a synchronous timer, just like the Winforms Timer.  Threading or one of the other Timer classes is *not* a substitute.  A single-shot is easy to implement, just set the timer's Enabled property to false in the Tick event handler.  No danger of a race:

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        ((Timer)sender).Enabled = false;
        // etc..
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx)? Use [one of the constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k93acx8.aspx) with the `period` parameter and specify the parameter accordingly.